# Apache Camel: ERROR WMQMsg - Expected MQ message characterSet '819', but received '1208'

Tags: character-encoding, apache-camel, ibm-mq

currently I am working with Apache Camel and trying to write to WMQ. But, unfortunatelly, I got above error. I found out to solve the problem, I will need to transform the character-set or encoding into "819" or "ISO-8859-1". But,  I do not know how to do so in apache camel.

Fyi, here is my route configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" default-init-method="init" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xs http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi  http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/components.xml"/>

    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route>
            <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8888/uebermittleAusweisdaten"/>
            <process ref="TransformToXML"/>
            <to uri ="xslt:mobako.sender.xsl"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelJmsDestinationName">
                <constant>queue:///LSMH.ZKSEAP.SERVICEBUS?targetClient=1</constant>    
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="jms:queue:LSMH.ZKSEAP.SERVICEBUS"/>
        </route>
        <route>
            <from uri="jms:queue:ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS"/>
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </route>

    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the encoding like so:

```
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

More info here: http://camel.apache.org/convertbodyto.html

Comment: I have tried to do so, but it did not work and I still got the error.

Comment: Where did you place it in your route?

Comment: I tried to place it after the setHeader tag. And I also have tried to place it after the from tag